# how to show related produts by tag - shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a "Related Products" section on my Product page, based with 'Vatage' theme. Now it shows products that a related by "collection". Is it possible to show related products that have the **same Tag**? 
i tried with other codes, but i failed.. 
please somebody help me.

This is my related-products.liquid code.

Thanks.

```
{% capture number_of_related_products_to_fetch %}{{ number_of_related_products_to_show | plus: 1 }}{% endcapture %}

{% if collection == null or collection.handle == 'frontpage' or collection.handle == 'all' %}
{% assign found_a_collection = false %}
{% for c in product.collections %}
{% if found_a_collection == false and c.handle != 'frontpage' and c.handle != 'all' and c.all_products_count > 1 %}
{% assign found_a_collection = true %}
{% assign collection = c %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}


<div class="desktop-12 mobile-3">


  <h4 class="section-title">{{ 'products.product.related_products' | t }}</h4>

  <div id="product-loop">
    {% assign current_product_found = false %}
    {% for prod in collection.products limit: 7 %}
    {% if prod.title == product.title %}
    {% assign current_product_found = true %}
    {% else %}
    {% unless current_product_found == false and forloop.last %}
    <div class="product-index desktop-2 tablet-2 mobile-half" id="prod-{{ product.id }}" data-alpha="{{ prod.title }}" data-price="{{ prod.price }}">  
      <a href="{{ prod.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ prod.title | escape }}">
        <img src="{{ prod.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape }}" />
      </a>

      <div class="product-info"> 

        <div class="product-info-inner">  
          <a href="{{ prod.url | within: collection }}"> 
            <h3>{{ prod.title }}</h3>
          </a>        
          <div class="price">
            {% if product.price < prod.compare_at_price %}
            <div class="onsale">{{ prod.price | money }}</div>
            <div class="was">{{ prod.compare_at_price | money }}</div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="prod-price">{% if prod.price_varies %} {{ 'products.general.from' | t }} {{ prod.price_min | money }} - {{ prod.price_max | money }} {% else %}{{ prod.price | money }}{% endif %}</div>
            {% endif %} 
          </div>

        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Related Products by Tag in Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407485/how-to-show-related-products-by-tag-in-shopify)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Solution brought to you by Caroline Schnapp -->
<!-- See this: http://wiki.shopify.com/Related_Products -->

{% assign image_size = 'compact' %}
{% assign heading = 'Other fine products' %}

{% if product.tags.size > 0 %}

<h3>{{ heading }}</h3>
<ul class="related-products"></ul>

<style type="text/css">
.related-products { list-style-type:none }
{% case image_size %}
{% when 'small' %}
.related-products * { font-size:12px; text-align:center; padding:0 }
.related-products h4  { border:none; margin:10px 0 0 0; line-height:1.3 }
.related-products div.image { height:100px }
.related-products li { float:left; width:120px; height:160px; margin-right:20px }
{% when 'compact' %}
.related-products * { font-size:13px; text-align:center; padding:0 }
.related-products h4  { border:none; margin:5px 0 0 0; line-height:1.5 }
.related-products div.image { height:160px }
.related-products li { float:left; width:180px; height:220px; margin-right:25px }
{% when 'medium' %}
.related-products * { font-size:14px; text-align:center; padding:0 }
.related-products h4  { border:none; margin:10px 0 0 0; line-height:1.8 }
.related-products div.image { height:240px }
.related-products li { float:left; width:260px; height:300px; margin-right:25px }
{% endcase %}
.related-products { overflow:hidden }
.related-products span.money { font-size:0.8em }
.related-products li:last-child { margin-right:0 }
</style>

<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
{{ 'api.jquery.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//<![CDATA[
  var recommendations = [];
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
  recommendations.push('{{ tag | handle }}');
  {% endfor %}
  if (recommendations.length) {
    var list = jQuery('ul.related-products');
    for (var i=0; i<recommendations.length; i++) {
      jQuery.getJSON(recommendations[i] + '.js', function(product) {
        list.append('<li><div class="image"><a href="' + product.url +'"><img src="' + product.images[0].replace(/(\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif)/, '_{{ image_size }}$1') + '" /></a></div><h4><a href="' + product.url + '">' + product.title + '</a></h4><span class="money">' + Shopify.formatMoney(product.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span></li>');
      });
    }
  }
//]]>
</script>

{% endif %}
```

Reference : https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/1002949

Or use paid apps from store.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  i've already tried with that code, and it doesn't work.  i don't know why, what's the problem.   so that's why i asked on here.   thanks-